# Symmetric sparse direct solvers in scipy

Tags: python, linear-solver, sparse-matrix, scipy

[`scipy.linalg.solve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve.html), in its newer versions, has a parameter `assume_a` that can be used to specify that the matrix $A$ is symmetric or positive definite; in these cases, LDL or Cholesky are used rather than LU (Lapack's `sysv` and `posv` rather than `gesv`).

**Is there a similar interface for sparse solvers?** As far as I understand, [`scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve) does not support `assume_a` and always uses LU. What is the recommended way to use a symmetric sparse direct solver in Scipy, then (if there is any at all)?

I have seen that there is also [`sksparse.cholmod`](https://scikit-sparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cholmod.html), but it is a separate package with a different interface, and from the documentation it looks like it does not handle indefinite matrices at all.

Comment: For Cholesky, $A$ must of course be nonnegative definite, eigenvalues $\ge 0$. E.g. `sksparse.cholmod.cholesky( A, beta=1e-6 )` does $A + 10^{-6} I \to L L'$. Is that what you want ?

Comment: @denis I was hoping to find also something for truly indefinite matrices like LDL (something that can solve a system with $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, for instance). And I was hoping to find it in `scipy` rather than in another package, but that may be asking too much. :)

Comment: Would you know of test cases for such problems, with matrices, on the web ?  Thanks

Comment: @denis You can find a lot of them if you select "numerical symmetry property: symmetric indefinite" in the [Matrix market search tool](https://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/searchtool.html). For instance [these ones](https://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/data/Harwell-Boeing/bcspwr/bcspwr.html).

Comment: Would you know of problems for generalized eigenvalues, pairs $A, M$ ? Matrixmarket is from 1999 / 2004, a long time ago (Moore's laws of cpus, memory, software, maybe eigenvalue algorithms too). Thanks

Comment: @denis I am only familiar with Matrix market and with [this collection](https://sparse.tamu.edu/), so I cannot help you much more with that.

Comment: @denis Anyway, your question looks like it should be a separate question here on this site, not a comment, if it does not refer specifically to my question.